# Calling background page function from a popup page NOT working (chrome extension)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For some odd reason, I can't seem to call a background page function from a popup.html javascript. (the JS is not inlined, but a seperate script).

**popup.js (a script referenced from popup.html)**

```
var bgPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
// debugger shows here that bgPage is indeed != null, 
// also - bgPage.myFunc prints my function, yay!

// However, calling the function does nothing, and quits
// the debugging without any exception
bgPage.myFunc();
```

**background.js**

```
function myFunc() { 
     console.log(1); // never happens
}
```

Why is that?
It sounds to me related to some security policy... not allowing me to call bg functions... maybe?

btw: Tried Message Passing also, didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. my bad...

The background.js had exceptions thrown, and I didn't notice it until I opened the dev tools for it.

problem solved.

Comment: As a comment, `chrome.extension.getBackgrounPage` should be considered deprecated in favor of `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage`. The former doesn't work with Event pages.

Comment: @Xan `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage` is *not* deprecated. If you're consciously using background pages over event pages (e.g. because you're using a long-running `WebSocket`), then c.e.gBP will always work as expected.